# why std::move uses std::remove_reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

`std::move` is declared as follows:

```
template <typename T>
std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t);
```

As far as my understanding goes, when code is templated, the  deduction of `T` in `typename T` looses information about reference, so following:

```
template <typename T>
void someFunction(T&& value);
```

when used like:

```
int five=5;
someFunction(five);
```

then

- `value` is of type `int&`
- `T` is `int`

or

```
const float value = 5.25;
someFunction(value);
```

then

- `value` is of type `const float&`
- `T` is `const float`.

If this is so, then there is no point in move declaration to declare returned type as:
`std::remove_reference<T>::type&&`, because T is already not a reference.

Moreover, if `std::move` takes as argument a reference (l-value reference in practice), then returning `static_cast<T&&>(t)` in `std::move` in fact due to reference collapsing will return l-value reference or r-value reference, so it will behave more like `std::forward` not move. So what is a trick, that makes it work properly, that I do not understand?

Comment: `T` must be `int&` if `value` is to be `int&`. Reference collapsing. And you don't want that to happen for the return type, you want it to be r-value reference at all times.

Comment: I once made this very same mistake.  How embarrassing! :-) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm#Returning%20A&&

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your examples are incorrect:

```
int five=5;
someFunction(five);
```

In this case, `T` is deduced as `int&`, not `int`. The same goes for the second example; `T` is deduced as `const int&`.

As such, returning just `T&&` would mean `T&& &`, which is `T&` due to reference collapsing rules.

This is why the `std::remove_reference` is required, to ensure that there are no references on the type to prevent reference collapsing from taking place.

Comment: what would be T then, if I had a function following:
template <typename T>
void function(T& a, T&& b); ?

Comment: @DawidPi and pass what to it?

Comment: yeah right sorry, int a, b, function(a,std::move(b));

Comment: `T` is `int` in that case.

Comment: could you try to explain why?

Comment: @DawidPi Template deduction rules are pretty complicated. Essentially, references are usually not deduced for `T`, but there's a special case for `T&&` parameters which states that `A&` is used instead of `A` if the argument is an lvalue (where `A` is the type of the argument).